# Reactjs: npm start error- Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

**not able to run the npm start**
After trying to npm start, it's giving error of

```
(node:5132) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:466:5
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\Web Development\Projects\Warehouse-Management\warehouse-management-client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.7.0
```

I've tried in many ways like remove and reinstall node_modules & react-scripts, uninstall many dependencies, restart projects, update node version. But still not solving.

Comment: Maybe try older versions of node. The project should specify which version it supports. Note that [LTS is 18](https://nodejs.org), so you should at least try that.

Comment: Node.js v19.7.0.
it's max updated version

Comment: Yes I'm saying that it may be too up to date, so you should try versions < 19.

Comment: Projects built on node version X, will not necessarily run on node versions > X.

Comment: no bro, it's not working

Answer (score 1):

After long time I can solve this.

```
npm audit fix --force
```

This was rescuer to me.

> Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Do fresh `npm install`.
3. Then do `npm audit fix --force`.

This should solve your issue. Also, remember to use node LTS version.